# Prove between any two real roots of $e^x\sin x =1$ there is at least one real roots of $e^x\cos x=-1$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Prove between any two real roots of $e^x\sin x =1$ there is at least one real roots of $e^x\cos x=-1$

Tried to use Rolle's theorem, chose 
$$f(x)=e^x\sin x-1$$
Let $a$ and $b$ are two roots for this function, where $a<b$, so 
$$f(a)=0$$
and 
$$f(b)=0$$
So there exist at least one points $\mu \in (a,b)$ s.t.
$$f'(\mu)=e^{\mu}\sin \mu + e^{\mu}\cos \mu=0$$
So
$$e^{\mu}\cos \mu=-e^{\mu}\sin \mu$$
However, $e^{x}\sin x=1$ was obtained at the end point of $[a,b]$, but $\mu \in (a,b)$.

Any ideas about how to go further? Thanks~

Comment: Set $f(x)=e^xcos(x)$. Then $f'(x)=-e^xsin(x)+f(x)$. Are you sure you can not see how to use Rolle here?

Comment: @dlc So choosing the interval $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ like say, then at the end point we have $f(x)=0$. So there exist at least one $\mu \in (\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ s.t. $f'(\mu)=0$. Which means $f(\mu)=e^x\sin x=1$. However, the question is about $-1$. So is the problem wrong? Or how could I use $e^x\sin x =1$?

Comment: You also want to differentiate correctly!

Comment: Yes, @NanLi, I got stuck doing that, too. So read my hint below. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Like I said the $\mu$ is in the open interval $(a,b)$, but in the open interval $(a,b)$, we are not necessarily have $e^x \sin x=1$ since they occurred at the end points, I mean at $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider two consecutive zeroes $a$ and $b$ of $f(x)=e^x\sin x - 1$. Then note that $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ have opposite signs. What does this tell you about $e^a\cos a$ and $e^b\cos b$?

Comment: If $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ have opposite signs, then there exist at least one point $\mu \in (a,b)$ s.t. $f'(\mu)=0$?

Comment: But you already observed that doesn't help you.  Did you answer my question about $e^a\cos a$ and $e^b\cos b$?

Comment: If $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ have opposite signs, so $e^a\sin a +e^a\cos a$ and $e^b\sin b +e^b\cos b$ have opposite signs. Since $e^a\sin a=e^b \sin b=1$, so $1+e^a\cos a$ and $1+e^b\cos b$ have opposite signs. So one of the $e^a \cos a$ and $e^b \cos b$ should be $> -1$ and the other should $< -1$. So there exist at least one point $\mu \in (a,b)$ s.t. $e^{\mu}\cos \mu =-1$. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!